# Problema com alteração de trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Tenho uma tabela que recebe dados o tempo todo, quase todos os segundos. Essa tabela possui uma trigger que após a inserção de uma linha nova insere esse registro em outra tabela.

Estou precisando incluir uma nova trigger na mesma tabela e tenho algumas questões:

1 - Quando tento alterar a trigger existente ou criar uma nova trigger, tudo para (a tabela para de receber registros e consequentemente a trigger nao escreve na outra tabela), além disso demora muito para que a alteração da trigger seja efetuada, tipo 5 minutos. Por que isso? Existe alguma forma de fazer isso de forma mais correta, sem travar nada ou demorar pra rodar?

2 - Existe alguma forma de pegar o log de erro do momento em que trava tudo para que eu saiba o que está ocorrendo?

OBS: Já tentei tanto inserir uma nova trigger quanto adicionar o meu código a trigger existente, ambas demoram pra rodar e ambas travam a tabela.

Estou disposto a incrementar a questão com mais informações, se necessário.

Comment: Você esta tentando inserir uma nova trigger ou alterar uma existente?

Comment: Já tentei das duas formas, ambas demoram pra rodar e ambas travam a tabela.

Comment: Se a trigger é muito usada ela pode ficar "locada" a aplicação "loca" a tabela ?

Comment: Sim, ela é muito usada, e deve estar lockando a tabela. E justamente esse ponto que não tenho conhecimento. De como previnir esse lock.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo: Sua dúvida é típica de "SQL Server Internals"...

Comment: Infelizmente, em sql server não dá para criar um disabled trigger. Não tem nenhuma altura que a tabela pare de receber essa informação todos os segundos?

Comment: Você precisará tirar a aplicação do ar temporariamente. Tente colocar o banco em 'single user' para realizar esta alteração e depois voltar o estado do banco.